# Repeated measures alternative regression?

Tags: r, regression, mean, random-effects-model

Say I measure an outcome variable at two given times (always the same) for 100 people.
For example their weights today and tomorrow, or before and after a treatment.

In order to find if the outcome depends on time I could perform a paired t-test or use a lineal regression model with random effects such as:

$Y = a+b·t+(1|ID)\quad\quad$    (lme4 notation; t=0 and 1; ID is each person)

I've also thought of fitting a model like this:

$Y_1 = a+b·Y_0$
or
$Y_1-Y_0 = a+b·Y_0$

Where $Y_0$ is the outcome at t=0, and $Y_1$ is the outcome at t=1.

I would like to know more about the latter model.  How do you call these kind of model?.
There is something similar in economitrics, they call it autoregressive models. Can I apply its formalism here?

I think I heard about them many years ago and somebody told me they have more statistic power and are better to observe the regression towards the mean.

I would also like to know the best way to generalize it when you have more measures in time.
Something like
$Y_{i+1} = a_i+b_i·Y_i$
or with dummy variables.